# django updating m2m field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model service and a ModelForm named Service which I use to add and update the service model. The model looks like this:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

The categories field is displayed as a  tag with that allows multiple selection. It works well when I'm adding a new record but when I'm updating it, only one service is showing up on the request.POST['categories'] even if I selected multiple categories.

I tried dumping the request object and I can see that the categories is showing something like:

```
u'categories': [u'3', u'4', u'2']
```

I tried calling the request._get_post() and it did return only 1 category, hence the request.POST['categories'] returns only 1. Anybody who knows what's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you supply details of the widget that's rendering the multiple choices as a tag field? perhaps that's not working correctly...

Comment: its using django's default widget for ManyToMany relationship which shows as a select tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use

```
request.POST.getlist('categories')
```

which will return all the selected values for that form field.